# Why is my Lightning Domain Not Available?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sandbox, lightning-apps, app, sandbox-refresh

After performing a Sandbox refresh this afternoon, I continued working on a Lightning app I am building. When I tried to preview the app from Developer Console in my Sandbox I received the following error:

> "Lightning Domain Not Available DNS Entry for Lightning is not
>   available yet. Cannot redirect to
>   https://recruitment--TandemDev.lightning.force.com/c/EmployeeSelfService.app.
>   Please try again later."

The refresh completed at 1:16PM EDT. It is now 5:08 PM EDT and the domain is still not available. It appears the instance location changed after the refresh so I don't know if that is part of the problem.

I wasn't sure if there are normally domain issues like this that will resolve themselves after some time or if I need to create a ticket with Salesforce support?

Comment: I've noticed that it can Salesforce some time to do a full refresh of all the goodies. I would wait until tomorrow morning and things should be caught backup.

Comment: looks like a known issue.. this might help you : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YcLAAU

Comment: Vamsi, according to that issue, that bug reported there was fixed in a recent patch at the end of June. I didn't experience this issue while using Lightning App Builder and disabling Salesforce1 BETA didn't fix this issue. I have had it disabled all along.

Comment: then its worth raising a support case with SF and let them handle this.

Comment: As an update, I checked again today and the issue still exists. I think there may be a bug with Lightning Apps not being correctly associated to a new Sandbox instance.

Comment: Hey guys, as an update. We are still checking with Salesforce on this one and it is still pending.

Comment: Any update @Erunamo114?  I am having this issue as well

Answer (score 1):

I talked to Salesforce about this issue. I showed them the issue over a screen share.  They said it falls under developer support, which is for premium or premier customers only, and that they could not help me, but it does seem like a bug.

I was able to work around this by deleting the sandbox, and recreating it. I did change the name as well during this process, since I wanted to make sure the domain was different just in case.  So this is not a great solution, but maybe the only option if you do not have developer support.